# Is Django Apache or Nginx

Tags: django, ssl, https, certbot

I have made a project in the framework Django and I am setting up SSL encryption so it gets https instead of http and removes the safety sign in browsers. In the installation process of Certbot I am asked which software it is running. Django is sadly not an option. I've heard that Django often gets under the category Apache or Nginx, but I am not sure which one my Django project is.
It is an Ubuntu server.

https://certbot.eff.org/
https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/#with-shell-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is any of them. I believe you have 2 options, install [certbot-django](https://certbot-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) or stop django server and let certbot to create a certificate for you, and then adapt it to django appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Django is neither.

Apache or Nginx is the web server that will serve your Django application - Django has no bearing or opinion on that.

You just need to figure our which webserver you're using and go from there. If you haven't already set up the webserver then you'll need to pick one and follow a tutorial to set it up.

For example, [here's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) how to set up Nginx with Django. But please do your own research on which one is best for you and your situation. An alternative to both could be [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com) for example.